# ASP.Net Core 2.2: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, sap-dotnet-connector

I recently started with ASP.Net Core 2.2. I have a situation where I need to use legacy SAP Connector library within my application. After some reading I created my application to target full .Net Framework 4.6.1. I have a test class that references the SAP Connector library.

However, when I run my application, it breaks within Startup.cs right where it calls this line:

```
app.UseMvc();
```

Checking the LoaderExceptions property, it shows the error: 
*Could not load file or assembly 'sapnco, Version=3.0.0.42, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50436dca5c7f7d23' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.*

My hunch is that although ASP.Net Core supports full .Net Framework, the referenced assembly has to go as far back to particular version of .Net Framework and no less. Although I can't find any concrete info on that.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

For SAP Connector, I think you need to contact SAP Forum Support to confirm if the SAP Connector .NET Core version is available or will be available.

From the perspective of .Net Core, I am afraid there are no connectors and no plans to develop such connectors.